# npm install fail with some package not found on some server

Tags: npm

I am on different servers and run `npm install`

One server is ok. Another failed showing below error:

> no matching version found for es-abstract@1.14.0

I tried `npm ci`. Same deal.

Then I did `npm install es-abstract-1.14.0.tgz`

But the size node_modules/ are different. I am using `du -shc --apparent-size node_modules/` to ignore the `sparse` files within the folder. Why?

Could I accept that this is the network issue of the failed server？ And just keep doing this? I mean, is the installation still going to be ok in this way?

Answer (score 2):

At the time that this answer was written, there are 33 release versions for [es-abstract on github](https://github.com/ljharb/es-abstract/releases), but only 32 release versions are listed on its [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-abstract).  The missing version in the registry is 1.14.0.

Perhaps on one of your servers, you had this package cached (maybe it was previously listed on the NPM registry?, or maybe from downloading it from github?), and on the other server you did not have this package cached.

I had this same error message when trying to npm install a project from github. 
 In my situation, the es-abstract package was not explicitly listed in the package.json file, but it was a dependency of another package. Therefore I explicitly added it with the next highest version listed on the registry, and it worked.

e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
    "es-abstract": "1.14.1",
    ...
```

Just a guess, but maybe 1.14.0 used to be listed on the registry, but now it's not?

Comment: There actually was a version 1.14.0. A lot of packages are depending on that version and it exists as a tag on the Github repository and I also have a local version of it in my node_modules.

Comment: OK @Itrulia, please help me then.  Why is it that when I go to https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-abstract and click on the list of 32 versions, then i don't see 1.14.0?  And how come my steps fixed the issue for me?

Comment: @KarlWenzel you just saved me! My pipeline just started failing out of the blue because this package was removed from the registry. Great short term fix til the author updates their dependencies.